# if string contains else if it doesn't contain - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am simply trying to check whether a string, in this case the document title, contains a certain word, and if it does display "str1" if it doesn't contain the certain word display "str2"

```
var str1 = document.title.replace(/NEW - Business Name/i, '');
var str2 = document.title.replace(/ - Business Name/i, '');
if(document.title.indexOf("Sale") == 1){
document.write(str1);}  else
if(document.title.indexOf("Sale") != 1){
document.write(str2);}
```

Comment: And the problem you're having with your code is...?

Comment: So... What _is_ the `document.title` you're testing with?  What is/isn't happening?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `== -1`?

Comment: `indexOf("Sale") == 1` checks if the word "Sale" starts at index `1` (i.e. at the second character) so it will be true for "XSale now" but not for "Sale now" or "We have a Sale".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [IndexOf docs](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)

```
var str1 = document.title.replace(/NEW - Business Name/i, '');
var str2 = document.title.replace(/ - Business Name/i, '');
if(document.title.indexOf("Sale") > -1){
document.write(str1);
}
else if(document.title.indexOf("Sale") === -1){
document.write(str2);
}
```

Comment: This worked, thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

**[`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)** method returns `-1` if string not contains the value else it will return index of the string. So change your if condition. Also there is no need for second `if` condition

```
if (document.title.indexOf("Sale") > -1) {
  document.write(str1);
} else {
  document.write(str2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think on your indexOf comparisons, you want `!= -1`, not `== 1`, if position of the word doesn't matter. (And the inverse, `== -1`, for the negative check)